# Eclipse: Autocompletion for Spring beans in Spring WebFlow?

Tags: eclipse, spring, spring-webflow

I am using Spring Web Flow 1.0 and Spring 2.0 (beans are defined in XMLs).

In eclipse (Indigo 3.7), I'd like to enable autocompletion for my beans when writing web flows. I am already using Spring IDE plugin.

Example (I'd like to prompt autocompletion for action - bean and method):

```
<action-state id="doDeleteSelection">
        <action bean="pm.TypoController" method="doDeleteElement" />
        <transition to="elements" />
</action-state>
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Use the JetBrains IDEA http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2009/03/spring-webflow-support-in-intellij-idea-8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  This behavior is available in the Spring WebFlow editor.  SpringIDE provides basic WebFlow editing using this editor.  If you want a more sophisticated graphical editor, then you should download SpringSource Tool Suite:

http://www.springsource.com/developer/sts

It is possible to install STS into an existing Eclipse instance.

I must say that I am a little surprised that you are not finding this feature since the use of the webflow editor should be default for all webflow files.  Perhaps there is another problem going on.

Comment: Well I am searching web and I see this should be included in Spring IDE indeed. The problem at my side seems that my Spring beans are unknown to web flow editor, so it can't autocomplete. On fresh project with dummy beans everything works well, so I guess problem lies elsewhere :( Thanks for pointing me the right direction anyway :)